# returning variables from a thread process function in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, arguments, return

I'm working on a thread that updates a variable of the main process.  As I did not succeed passing arguments I had to use global.  But I don't like it, it's not safe.  There is any way without using global?

I can pass the argument, but my issue is with the returning object.

My code:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import threading
import time

my_check = " CHECK "    # TODO replace with initial source data.

class MiThread(threading.Thread):   
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):  
        time.sleep(5)
        print("I'm the SECOND thread")
        global my_check
        my_check = " CHECK DONE!!!" # TODO replace with the updated source data.
        self.run()

print ("I'm the principal thread.")

t = MiThread()     
t.start()       
#t.join(1)        

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("I'm the principal thread, too." + my_check)
```

This is only a concept proof, really I want to code a little stocks ticker displayer in a tkinter label, and I need, at least two more threads: the updater thread (for update the information to display) and the displayer thread (it must changes the text of the label each 0.3 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store result of thread execution in instance variable of thread object:

```
import threading
import time

class MiThread(threading.Thread):   
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_check = " CHECK "
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):  
        time.sleep(5)
        print("I'm the SECOND thread")
        self.my_check = " CHECK DONE!!!"

print ("I'm the principal thread.")

t = MiThread()     
t.start()         

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("I'm the principal thread, too." + t.my_check)
```